# is it normal for USB 3 external disks to take 5 minutes to mount?

Tags: hard-drive, disk-utility, imac, usb, monterey

I have a 2020 M1 Mac and an old 27" late 2012 iMac.

I have two USB 3 disks, both encrypted APFS with two partitions. One is 5TB and the other is 1TB. Both use regular hard drives, NON-SSD.

I connect the 5TB disk on the M1 Mac and the first partition (4TB) mounts and appears on finder after 2 minutes and 50 seconds. The second partition takes 5 minutes and 30 seconds to appear.

I tried the same disk on the old iMac. The first partition (4TB) takes 2 minutes and 10 seconds to appear and the second one, 2 minutes and 50 seconds.

Once or twice a week both USB disks I have on these new Mac unmount without reason forcing macOS to pop a message telling me that the disks were removed without ejecting.

Disk Utility says both disks and partitions are ok.

All disks are connected directly to the Mac USB ports.

I have reinstalled Monterey on the new iMac, just in case.

The big questions:

1. why they mount fast on the old iMac using Catalina?
2. are these times normal?
3. are these disks failing?
4. is the USB failing internally?
5. is there some terminal utility I can use to check the disks?

Answer (score 1):

Usually you can spot some version of `fsck` running when this happens. It is a file system check and the system runs it for you and until it’s done, you won’t see the disk mount.

- https://support.apple.com/en-mk/guide/activity-monitor/welcome/mac

You may need to use the menu to show all processes to find this, since it runs without any app visible. If this is what’s happening, getting a faster disk or changing it so journaling is enabled will speed the time to check as will taking time to eject the disk properly.

You should be able to see the check logs in console app to validate the disks mount after the check completes in each case.